# What are the border definitions in the Ramachandran plot?

Tags: biochemistry

I've heard some people mention that this or that program isn't "up to date" with respect to the borders used in the Ramachandran plots to classify φ/ψ as being in the most favorable/acceptable/disallowed regions.

How *are* the accepted regions defined?  What is the current accepted paper that covers this?

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could answer your question outright, but this is outside my area of expertise. The best I can give you is a place to start. I expect any recent book on proteomics would cover this topic. For example [Introduction to Proteomics: Principles and Applications (Methods of Biochemical Analysis)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471754021) by Mishra and Blobel, Wiley 2010.

I found some promising papers with a little searching with SciFinder. Neither I nor my institution subscribe to *Protein Science*, but the abstract looks promising. I have skimmed the article in *PNAS*. Hopefully one of these articles has your answer.

Zhou, *et al*, ["Revisiting the Ramachandran plot from a new angle"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/pro.644), *Protein Science* **2011** 1166-1171.

Porter and Rose, ["Redrawing the Ramachandran plot after inclusion of hydrogen-bonding constraints"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1014674107), *PNAS*, **2011*, 108, 1, 109-112